# Is there a way in Firefox to control how a link opens based on which site you are on?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, browser-tabs

When I'm on my home page (www.google.com, for example), I would like all links to open in a new tab even if it explicitly orders the link to open in a new window. On the other hand, I would like all links on Hulu to open in a new window.

Is there a method in Firefox that allows you to control how links open based on the domain/site you are in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Firefox with [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122) to do this so *sort of* do what you want.

While it doesn't allow specific behaviors based on the site you are on, I get the same effect by configuring what the mouse buttons do.

I have it set up like this:

- **LeftClick** - Load the page like normal but, if the page tries to open in another window, it forces the page to open in another tab instead.
- **MiddleClick** - Open the page in a new tab.
- **SHIFT-LeftClick** - Open the page in another window.

You can set it up any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

What i do is change the option [Browser.link.open_newwindow](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow#1) to 1 in about:config. Then left click if I want to open it in the same tab, middle click in a new tab and shift+click in a new window.